# Javascript function executing too many times

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

[This is how i populate the table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aekhw.png)
I'm having some trouble with the datatables plugin for jquery. The table is populated dynamically, I have 3 columns with text and a fourth column which consists of a delete and an edit button. For the edit button I have a modal, and if I confirm the changes, it does indeed change the specific line in the table. 
However, if I click on several edit buttons and cancel, when I actually want to change one it changes all the previously canceled lines. 
Here is the relevant code:

```
$("#example").on("click", ".edit-button", function() {
  $("#edit-modal").modal("show");
  saveChanges(this);
});
function saveChanges(k) { 
  $("#edit-confirm").click(function() {
  $(".itm-loader-modal").show();
  setTimeout(function() {editJob(k);},1000); 
  });
}
function editJob(currentButton) {
  $(".itm-loader-modal").fadeOut("slow");
  var editedName = $("#job-name").val();
  var editedDescription = $("#job-description").val();
  var editedCompany = $("#job-company").val();
  var data = {
   "name":editedName,
   "description": editedDescription,
   "company": editedCompany
  };
  var currentLine = $(currentButton).parent().parent().children(); 
  currentLine.eq(0).text(data.name);
  currentLine.eq(1).text(data.description);
  currentLine.eq(2).text(data.company);
  $("#edit-modal").modal("hide");
}
```

Comment: code for cancel button ?

Comment: <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" id="edit-cancel" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>

Comment: I think I have an idea of what's causing your problem. You are looping through to display each item right? You need to append the `id` of each item, so edit selects only the clicked item. Show us more code so we can help.

Comment: I have no javascript code for the cancel button

Comment: I'm not actually looping through, i'm using the "data" property of the datatables plugin
 $('#example').DataTable( {
    "pagingType": "simple_numbers",
    "sScrollX": '100%',
    "language":{
      "zeroRecords": "Sal pa"
      },
    "mark": true,
    "data": [
      {
        "name":"Architect",
        "description":"Entry level Architect needed",
        "company":"Cornsa Builders",
        "actions":edit + remove
      },

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hard to say for sure, but one think that looks wrong is that each time `saveChanges` is called, you register new event listener on `#edit-confirm` button.

Once that `#edit-confirm` is clicked, it will execute all the registered event handlers – one for each `.edit-button` click.

Instead, you probably want to have a single `#edit-confirm` click handler and find a way to pass the info about the line that's currently being edited to it.

Cheers.

Comment: Thank you! I'll see if I can figure out a way to pass the info and I'll get back here.

Comment: Did you manage to solve the issue. Dont forget to mark the correct question. ;)

Answer (score 0):

so when you call saveChanges it assign event handler to `"#edit-confirm"`, all those event handlers are executed at once,

to avoid it you should attach event handler to it via delegation or i think this quick fix should work

```
$(this).find('#edit-confirm').click(function() {
/...
})
```